Manual indexing with multidimensional cupy ndarray in user defined kernels
In the cupy docs on user defined kernels (https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/user_guide/kernel.html), there is a section defining certain variables that are predefined, like _ind.size() and i for things like manual indexing in element-wise kernels.
It seems like these variables are make sense only for 1D arrays; I was wondering how they scale/change for larger multidimensional arrays; explicit references to element-wise manipulation of ndarrays are not really given anywhere (to my knowledge).

The word size, in the context of numpy and cupy, refers to the total number of elements in a multidimensional array. So _ind.size() is probably the same as arr.size() where arr is the array after broadcasting the inputs. And i, I suppose, goes from 0 to arr.size()-1.
This may seem strange if you are used to multidimensional indexing like arr[x_ind, y_ind, z_ind], but it's natural from the perspective of C++, where arr[i] means "thing at memory address &arr + i.
